# Video stream with delay

Tags: video

I need to capture a video stream from a web cam and then show it non-stop with a delay of 30 seconds or more.

A server side linux software would be the best but a Windows GUI application will be ok as well.

Comment: simultaneously capture and stream?

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum I think he means to capture the footage, wait several seconds (30, 60, etc...) and then play it. I'm not sure if that counts as simultaneous or not.  To OP: Could you elaborate a bit on the question? What is the final goal of this? What sort of stream is it (wmv, asf, mms, etc...)?

Comment: to me it sounds like he wants to restream something essentially

Comment: Yes you right. I want to capture and replay. It's stays in some buffer. Immediately after X seconds you can see it on some projector/display. I don't care about formats(any mp4, wmv asf, raw data in memory or on disk drive). I need cheap/reliable solution. As less programming as possible since I believe VLC and FFMpeg can do it somehow.

Comment: What is the source? Is it an online stream? Could you provide a link? Why don't you just use the original stream on the display? All this info would help to find a solution and make the question more helpsful to others as well.

Comment: Normal web camera connected to computer is source of stream. I cannot show immediately cos task is show with delay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a **Broadcast Delay Processor**. Unfortunately, these processors come as a hardware device that you feed your signal through, and therefore they are relatively expensive.

I did look around for a software based broadcast delay for you, but I was not able to find any.

Luckily though, you can use [VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) (free and available on Linux and Windows) to stream with a delay. Check out this command:

> Display stream output
>
> ```
>   --sout-display-delay=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
>                              Delay (ms)
>       Introduces a delay in the display of the stream.
> ```

In your case use it like with this value:  `--sout-display-delay=30000`

You can also record your webcam with VLC, see this article for details:
[Recording webcam videos with VLC Media Player](http://newcome.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/recording-webcam-videos-with-vlc-media-player/)

In other words, using VLC with the provided commands you should be able to both record your webcam and stream it with a delay (at no cost).

Comment: I tried with the comand "--sout-display-delay=30000" but the delay doesn't work....
Any suggestion?
Thanks